# Hide div when iframe is empty

Tags: html, iframe, hide

How do I, in this case...

```
<div id="video-embeds" style="z-index:102;">
<div class="video-embed" style="margin-top: 0px; z-index:102; margin-bottom: 0px;">

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

</div>
</div>
```

...hide `#video-embeds` completely.

CSS or JQuery?

This is css that prevents me doing it...

```
.video-embed {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, there is no CSS parent selector. You will need to do it using Javascript.

Since you are using jQuery, here is a solution:

```
$('iframe').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('src') == '') {
    $(this).parent('.video-embed').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: I cant get it work in wordpress. I tried using jQuery(document).ready(function($) but still does not hide the div.

Comment: Done, I missed one ")" ... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by jQuery. Add `id="frame"` to frame 
`<iframe id="frame" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   var src = $("#frame").attr('src'); 
   if(src==''){
    $("#video-embeds").css("display: none;");
   }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $frame

Comment: sorry this is my mistake use `#frame`